# how to display div horizontal when click on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

at what i am trying to do in my below code when i click on all checkbox checked then div element is show horizontal using CSS

but right in my code when i click on checkbox checked then div is show vertical.

but i want to display horizontal means inline when i click checkbox

how can we do that using CSS

is there any help ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); 
                    $("." + inputValue).toggle(); 
                }); 
            });
```

```css
.selectt { 
            display: none; 
            margin-top: 30px; 
            width:20%; 
           
        } 
        
        label { 
            margin-right: 15px; 
        } 

       .d-flex-wrapper {
           display: flex;
       }
       .d-flex-wrapper > div{
           margin-right:5px;
       }
       .d-flex-wrapper > div:last-chid{
           margin-right:30px;
       }
       
       .button {

  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox"
                    value="C"> C</label> 
            <label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox"
                    value="Cplus"> C++</label> 
            <label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox"
                    value="Python"> Python</label> 
            <label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox"
                    value="Java"> Java</label> 
        </div> 
     <div class="d-flex-wrapper">  <!-- Added New div start here -->
        <div class="C selectt"> 
       <button class="button button2">c</button>
       <button class="button button2">c#</button>
        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="d-flex-wrapper"> 
        <div class="Cplus selectt"> 
       <button class="button button2">C++</button>
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">mysql</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">sql</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">database</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
       </div> 
       
       </div>
       
        
        <div class="Python selectt"> 
       <button class="button button2">python</button></div> 
        <div class="Java selectt"> 
        <button class="button button2">java</button></div>   <!-- Added New div end's here -->
    </div>
```

.

Comment: You just made a syntax mistake, see last div: https://jsfiddle.net/pmyu45td/

Answer (score 0):

There will be several approaches.

Using `flex`:

```
.d-flex-wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Using `grid`:

```
.d-flex-wrapper > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: i already use flex in my code above but its should not happen @adrisolid